# Complexity Classes for P-problems

Tags: complexity-theory

If a problem is in P (ie 3-Clique or any Clique problem with a fixed k) does that mean it is also in NP and CO-NP?

Comment: It is well known that $P \subseteq NP \cap coNP$

Comment: Thank you. What was tripping me up was I read co-NP was complement of NP so I was not sure if something could be both NP and Co-NP.

Comment: A language that is in $P$ must be both in $NP$ and $coNP$ because given a polynomial time algorithm that decides a language, one can easily construct an algorithm to decide its complement (just flip the output).